# Transfer AWS S3 static website to EC2 beanstalk

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I'm very new to aws web-hosting, so bear with me here.

Originally, I deployed a static business website on amazon s3 following their instructions - Only html, css, and some jquery.

I've now improved on that website, turning it into a node.js based express static app that includes a contact form that sends data through nodemailer - nothing complicated, no database necessary for function. However, it requires to be deployed on EC2, since it involves node.js.

My problem is: I can't find any resources online about how the make the transfer happen. I've searched AWS tutorials for hours, but can't find anything about my specific case.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You probably aren't finding anything because you wouldn't be "transferring" the website from S3 to EB, you would simply be creating a new website and deleting the old one. You would deploy a new website on Elastic Beanstalk. Then you would change any DNS records pointing to your S3 bucket to make them point to the new Elastic Beanstalk application. Once the DNS updates have propagated you could delete the old S3 bucket if you wanted.